# What are my language choices for lego NXT?

Tags: nxt, lego-mindstorms

It is unclear from wikipedia etc (without installing a bunch of crap and testing) which languages I can use to write programs which can be copied and run standalone on the NXT brick. What languages are currently supported? I'd probably want to go with something high-level like haskell, or at the very least a well-recognized language such as C, as opposed to NXT-G and NXC etc.

Answer (score 0):

These are some very common languages used to program the Mindstorms NXT:

- You could try ROBOTC, which will enable you to write programs in C
  for the Mindstorms NXT. (NXC is C like, yet not completely C, hence
  Not Exactly C)
- Otherwise you could try leJOS, which will enable you    to write
  programs in Java for the Mindstorms NXT.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of MSRDS. It's free (unlike ROBOTC) and if you are handy with C# the learning curve isn't to gnarly. I noticed it wasn't on that list :( so I thought I would throw in my two cents.